# In shell script, can I specify more than one output delimiter in cut?

Tags: bash, shell, command, sh

I have a file with the following data

> abcdefghijklmnopqrst

I need an output using command `cut` as the following

> bcd|klm.no|pq.rst

I need to include both the delimiters `|` and `.` in my output using cut.

I've got the output with one delimiter using this code

```
cat file.txt |cut -c2-4,11-13,14-15,16-17,18-20 --output-delimiter='|'
```

as

> bcd|klm|no|pq|rst

Can I get 2 output delimiters by changing something in the command?

Comment: Couldn't you run it through `cut` twice? Once for the first separator, and again for the second?

Comment: @gilez Yeah, you could.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cut` supports a single delimiter at a time, but you can easily replace this with a simple `sed` or Awk script.

```
awk '{ print substr($0, 2, 4) "|" substr($0, 11, 13) "."
   substr($0, 14, 15) "|" substr($0, 16, 17) "."
    substr($0,18, 20) }' file.txt
```

Coincidentally the [`cat` is useless](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html).

Answer (score 1):

With GNU sed:

```
$ sed -r 's/.(.{3}).{6}(.{3})(.{2})(.{2})/\1|\2.\3|\4./' file.txt
bcd|klm.no|pq.rst
```

Answer (score 1):

Two `cut`s (suggested by *Gilez*'s comment to OP):

```
cut -c2-4,11-15,16-20 --output-delimiter='|' file.txt | \
cut -c1-7,8-13,14-15  --output-delimiter='.'
```

Output:

```
bcd|klm.no|pqr.st
```

---

Given such regular input, `tr` can also "answer" this with no pipe:

```
tr -s 'a-t' 'b-d|k-m.no|p-r.st' < file.txt
```

Note: `tr` can't insert, so it sounds impossible.  Generally is *is* impossible, but the *cheat* is to include the answer in *SET2*, and squeeze out the rest.